# Cannot resolve method 'sumDouble(io.reactivex.Observable<java.lang.Double>)'

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

In Activity :

```
Double price = o.getDouble ( "totalprice" );

Observable<Double> floatObservable = Observable.just(price);

MathObservable
       .sumDouble(floatObservable)
       .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
       @Override
       public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onNext(Integer integer) {
             System.out.println("Sum: " + integer);
       }

       @Override
       public void onError(Throwable e) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onComplete() {

       }
});
```

Gradle :

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0'
```

Error occur at line :

.sumDouble(floatObservable)

Error :

> Cannot resolve method
>   'sumDouble(io.reactivex.Observable)'

Comment: rxjava-math does not support RxJava 2 nor is maintained. Use [RxJava 2 Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#releases) and its [math operators](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#mathematical-operations-over-numerical-sequences).

Comment: its sumDoubles().... if you check the source code 
 https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaMath/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/math/operators/OperatorSum.java

Comment: i added compile "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.20.8" this but still it didn't work. @akarnokd

Comment: It's sumDouble() not sumDoubles(). https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#mathematical-operations-over-numerical-sequences  @akshay_shahane

Comment: you have added this dependency    'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0' i am talking about this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.gradle add dependencies

```
  implementation "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.20.8"
```

then

```
 Observable<Double> floatObservable = Observable.just(1.2,1.3);

    MathObservable
            .sumDouble(floatObservable)
            .subscribe(new Observer<Double>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Double aDouble) {
                    System.out.println("Sum: " + aDouble);
                   //if you want int convert here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Its working fine ..answer is 2.5